# css3-mediaqueries-js causing big CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift)

Tags: javascript, css, seo, lighthouse, cls

According to Google Search Console and Chrome Lighthouse, my website is experiencing a very late cumulative layout shift (CLS), although it was never noticeable to me in normal use. After spending a day tracking it down, it seems to be originating from the [css3-mediaqueries-js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) file that is provided by Google. Any time that file is included, the CLS problem would be extreme (1s or longer). Removing it 100% fixed the CLS issue.

Has anyone else experienced this or know of a fix other than simply removing it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to get rid of the css-mediaqueries-js file. Any remotely new browser supports media queries at this point so this was only serving to jam up my site!